# How to validate before Ajax request at some central location?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-2

I have some Partial Views loaded in a View. All the Partial Views post by Ajax call in JQuery.
I have to impose some validation before sending request to server. For that I can use the **BeforeSend**

```
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    async: true,
    type: 'POST',
    data: JSON.stringify({ Parameters... }),
    beforeSend: function (xhr, opts) {

    },
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    complete: function () {  },
    success: function (data) {

    }
});
```

I have similar structures corresponding to all JQuery functions for their Partial Views. I can implement my validation part in **beforeSend**.

Is there any way to implement the validation at some centralized place and in case found not validated then abort the request at that central place ? **So that I do not need to write the same code(function calling) everywhere in each Ajax block)**

Comment: why not validate before the AJAX is called at all, and place the AJAX is an `if(valid)` statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
jQuery(window).load(function () {
    jQuery.ajaxSetup({
        beforeSend: function (xhr, opts) {
            if(Some Validation Fails) { //Validation check logic
                 xhr.abort();
                 debugger;
            }
        }
    });
});
```

### **Why window.load and Why not DOM Ready function ?**

Let all Partial views get loaded and once load done then on some button click let the above happen